# SharePoint Online Modern site: Cannot see yammer webpart (Conversation / Highlights)

Tags: sharepoint-online, modern-experience, administration, sitepages, yammer

I am trying to add a yammer Webpart in one of my Modern SharePoint online page.

When I search for the yammer in add new web part section, it says `we couldn't find anything that matched your search`. (Refer below snapshot)

Is there any settings that I need to do to make it available?

[image]

Comment: Are you using team site or communication site? Try searching for "Viva Engage". Check this once: https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/office/use-a-viva-engage-web-part-in-sharepoint-online-a53cfa0c-3d09-42c8-a286-1038a81c59da. Let me know if it works for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yammer is now renamed to **Viva Engage**.

Try searching for Viva Engage in web parts toolbox like:

[image]

**Documentation**: [Use a Viva Engage web part in SharePoint Online](https://support.microsoft.com/office/use-a-viva-engage-web-part-in-sharepoint-online-a53cfa0c-3d09-42c8-a286-1038a81c59da?wt.mc_id=MVP_315224)

Comment: Got it. Thanks!